# How do I archive an AOSP repo like git-archive doing?

Tags: android, android-source

I have used this command to archive a git source code:

```
git archive --format=tgz -o ~/myproj-20180402.tgz --prefix=myproj/ master
```

Are there same/similar way to archive a AOSP repo branch or tag. How to do ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

AOSP code is not a single **git** project, it's actually many more (hundreds). So there is not a **git** command per-se.

What you could do is use repo this way:

```
repo forall -j16 "<your-git-command-1; your-git-command-2>"
```

So for the exact git command you proposed it would be:

```
repo forall -j16 "git archive --format=tgz -o ~/myproj-20180402.tgz --prefix=myproj/ master"
```

But keep in mind there is not a ***single*** **git** project, so you will end up with hundreds of archives, each inside it's root dir. Check the manifest you sync for a full list of projects and it's location locally.

Comment: My intention was to make a single complete package to archive all source code exclude any .repo/.git files, just like git archive done. It seems that it is not feasible. In the end I solved it with the following method, it is ugly:

Comment: $ cp -a android.repo/ android-7.1.2_r36/
$ cd android-7.1.2_r36/
$ find -name ".repo" -exec rm -rf {} \;
$ find -name ".git" -exec rm -rf {} \;
$ cd ..
$ tar czf android-7.1.2_r36.tgz android-7.1.2_r36/
$ du -sh android.repo/ android-7.1.2_r36
75G     android.repo/
22G     android-7.1.2_r36

Comment: I think "repo forall" may also need to write a complicated script to handle the hierarchical relationship between each git project and Aosp repo.
The "repo forall" you recommend for me are very powerful. I got it, thank you!