# git-repo (aosp repo) tool checking-out projects again from local cache

Tags: repo, git-repo

We use the google git-repo tool (aosp repo) to manage a workspace of many git repositories. However, if you want to do a clean checkout that is exactly the same as the last workspace, using the command `repo sync` will pull in all the changes from remotes first.

How can you get the local repositories populated from only the local cache that is currently in the `.repo/` directory?

Comment: On another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603844/how-do-i-archive-an-aosp-repo-like-git-archive-doing it uses `forall` to iterate through individual git repos. Probably one solution can be like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
repo sync --local-only
```

From repo help:

```
$ repo help sync
[...]
-l, --local-only      only update working tree, don't fetch
```